# Stochastic Gradient Descent and Unbiased Estimators

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, stochastic-gradient-descent

In stochastic gradient descent, we utilize the fact that the sampled gradient is an unbiased estimator of the full gradient. That is, with the loss as:
$    \nabla \tilde{L} = \nabla \operatorname{loss}(\theta)$,

We have:
\begin{align*}
 \mathbb{E}[\nabla \tilde{L}] & = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{n} \nabla \operatorname{loss}_i(\theta)  \\
                      & = \frac1n \nabla \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \operatorname{loss}_i(\theta) \\
                      & = \nabla L
\end{align*}

However, I do not fully understand the rationale behind using an unbiased estimator. All an unbiased estimator says is that in the limit of large enough sample size, the expected value will converge to the true value. But according to the SGD formula above, the loss is dependent on the specific parameter $\theta$, which changes at each time step. If this changes, our probability distribution changes, and it seems having an unbiased estimator is meaningless.

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Your definition of an unbiased estimator is actually that of a *consistent* estimator; an unbiased estimator has an expected value equal to the true value, even with finite sample sizes.  It's OK if the probability distribution changes, as long as at each step the estimator is still unbiased and asymptotically it converges to the true value.

Comment: But what true value are we talking about? At each step, $\theta$ changes and therefore the gradient changes.

Comment: What is $\theta$?  The true parameter never changes, it is what it is.  Note that in your equations, $\theta$ is not indexed by $i$.

Comment: It was my understanding that $\theta$ represents the set of parameters at some time step $i$. Isn't that what we use to calculate the gradient?

Comment: If it changes at every step, you should index it by $i$, otherwise, confusion ensues, as it appears to be fixed.

Comment: My apologies. But then by the reasoning of stochastic gradient descent, wouldn't we only be able to approximate the expected loss at some timestep $i$ with some set of parameters $\theta_i$? But at each timestep, the expectation changes, so it would seem that at each time step we aren't necessarily getting any closer to some desired expected value.

Comment: Think of Newton's method.  The direction and stepsize change at each step, but you still get to the optimum.  Here you are calculating an "expected optimal direction" instead of the actual optimal direction, so at each step, the "expected optimal direction" changes, but you still get to the optimum.  I think you are confusing the expectation of the direction, which changes as you travel, with an expectation of the destination, which does not (so to speak.)

Comment: I guess I'm not completely convinced here still. Here we take the gradient to be the random variable and its distribution to be the gradients parameterized by $\theta$. Now this distribution should change depending on the $\theta_i$, no? If this isn't the right way to think about it, what are we considering the distribution of the gradient to be?